# how to spread column data to rownames

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to spread `name` column.

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3), 
                name = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d","c","d"))

|  ID | name |
|-----|------|
|  1  |  a   |
|  1  |  b   |
|  2  |  a   |
|  2  |  c   |
|  2  |  d   |
|  3  |  c   |
|  3  |  d   |
```

using `tidyr::spread()` can get like under the data.frame

```
d %>% tidyr::spread(name,name) 
| ID| a | b | c | d |
| 1 | a | b | NA| NA|
| 2 | a | NA| c | d |
| 3 | NA| NA| c | d |
```

but I want to get like this data.frame.

```
|  ID | name1 | name2 | name3 |
|-----|-------|-------|-------|
|  1  |   a   |  b    | NA    |
|  2  |   a   |  c    |   d   |
|  3  |   c   |  d    | NA    |
```

Comment: In base R, with `reshape`: `d$count <- ave(d$ID, d$ID, FUN=seq_along)` and then `reshape(d, direction="wide", idvar="ID", timevar="count")`.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a new column and `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new = paste0("name", row_number())) %>%
  spread(new, name)
#    ID  name1  name2  name3
#* <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
#1     1      a      b     NA
#2     2      a      c      d
#3     3      c      d     NA
```

---

It is relatively concise with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(d), ID~paste0("name", rowid(ID)), value.var = "name")
```